# Android API >= 30: Top bar always visible after double scrolling if app pinned

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, kiosk, android-statusbar, android-screen-pinning

If an app is pinned (using `startLockTask()`, eg. for kiosk mode) and the status bar is hidden using `WindowInsetsController.hide`, if the user will double scroll from top, status bar will be showed and never hides again (it should hide after a second). No other gesture can hide it.
The problem occurs for most devices, including emulator, for Android API >= 30.

Demo video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33pnOQBR9_I

Minimum code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startLockTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        hideSystemUI();
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            final Window window = getWindow();
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
            final WindowInsetsController insetsController = window.getInsetsController();
            insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
            insetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Run on Android API >= 30!");
        }
    }
}
```

How can it be fixed?